# Are there authoritative (canon) sources outside the movie for information about the new Star Wars narrative?

Tags: star-wars, canon, the-force-awakens

After having watched the new Star Wars movie, I looked up info about the new storyline, and found some articles with details --for example, that Kylo Ren's lightsaber was made from a cracked crystal --that I don't recall from the movie itself.  Are there other canon sources (outside the movie itself) for information about the new Star Wars continuity?

Comment: I think the crystal part is from the book as far as I understood

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes.

There are ([source: starwars.com](https://www.starwars.com/news/a-galaxy-of-star-wars-the-force-awakens-books-coming-december-18-first-look)):

- **Official novelizations**

  - Alan Dean Foster novelization
  - Michael Kogge "Junior" novelization
- **Reference materials**

  - Star Wars: The Force Awakens Visual Dictionary
  - The Art of Star Wars: The Force Awakens
  - Star Wars: The Force Awakens Incredible Cross-Sections
- **"Let's make more money for Disney" books**

  - Star Wars: The Force Awakens Ultimate Sticker Collection
  - Star Wars: Droid Factory
- Multiple Disney **books for kids**

  - Star Wars: Rey Meets BB-8 (Level 1 Reader)
  - Star Wars: Finn & Rey Escape! (8×8, w/stickers)
  - Star Wars: Han & Chewie Return! (8×8)
  - 5-Minute Star Wars Stories
  - Star Wars: The Force Awakens Flashlight Adventure Book
  - Star Wars: The Force Awakens – Lightsaber Rescue
  - Star Wars: The Force Awakens Mix & Match
  - Star Wars: The Force Awakens – Rey’s Survival Guide
  - Star Wars: Finn and the First Order
  - Star Wars: Look and Find
  - Star Wars: The Force Awakens New Adventures
- **Prequel books**

  - Aftermath (way way prequel)
  - Star Wars: Before the Awakening
  - 2016 New Republic: Bloodline book
- **General canon novels**

  Too many to list, see [Wookieepedia](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Timeline_of_canon_books).

  However, most of that list is either kid books, and/or set before Endor or its immediate aftermath.
- More **Marvel comics** [than you can shake your gaffa stick at](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Timeline_of_canon_comics)

  However, none of them are describing the events at the time of The Force Awakens yet - the latest ends around Battle of Endor or soon after.
- Star Wars Databank on starwars.com has articles with some info

Comment: I upvoted, but I have a question about the official novelizations --my understanding was that the new movie doesn't align with any earlier books, correct?  Is there a new novelization already out?  I wouldn't have guessed they would have released one prior to the movie...

Comment: @ChrisSunami - digital version of adult novelization was released. Dead tree in January.